# Javascript: Find a string inside a list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, associative

I have defined this structure:

```
var game_list = { 
    1: {name:'Vampires hunter', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
    2: {name:'Christmas vampires', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
    3: {name:'Fruit hunter', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
    4: {name:'The fruitis', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
    5: {name:'james bond', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
    6: {name:'Vampires hunter', description:'The best vampires game in the world'},
};
```

What I need to do (with plain js) is to create a function that find a string into that structure (the user can use small or caps), the func will have 2 parameters the array itself and the string to find.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: This not multidimensional array but array of object. Would you like to find description from this structure?

Comment: @Suman you are right (a newbie here), i have changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the structure of your data, it would make more sense to store the objects in an array, instead of nesting it inside an object like it is now.

That being said, you can use this function to find a string within the structure. It returns the object(s) which contains the string.

```
function findString(obj, str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var results = [];
    for(var elm in obj) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(elm)){
            continue;
        }
        for (var key in obj[elm]) {
            if (obj[elm].hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[elm][key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(str) > -1) {
                results.push(obj[elm]);
            }
        }
    }
    return results.length > 1 ? results : results[0];
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5aq2/)

Comment: thanks a lot @levi, thing is i can't change the structure since it´s im working within an already made code (work policies i guess), so im not pretty sure if your answer is forcing me to change the structure first, also i need to show the results.

Comment: @user3337697 I updated the answer to work with your existing structure. What you do with the results is a separate concern. I am logging the results simply to demonstrate the function.

Comment: im getting an error "Object1 has no method toLowerCase" in the console (Chrome) in this line "if (obj[elm].hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[elm][key].toLowerCase().indexOf(str) > -1)" Any idea of what's happening ? thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: im using the same structure and data as in the original question if that's what you mean.

Comment: weird. Do you get that error when viewing the demo `http://jsfiddle.net/g5aq2/` ?

Comment: nope, yeah thats weird. Just fyi if i delete the "!" symbol from this line if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(elm)) the console wont show me the error but the results array is empty while having matching strings to show.

Comment: Ok got it. It's the structure, i was using an object with more than two dimensions something like this :
var games_list = { 1: {id:1, name:"hercules total", description:"the best game ever"}, 2: {id:2, name:"HERCULES vampiresTOTAL", description:"the best game ever"}, 3: {id:3, name:"hercules vampires", description:"the best game ever"}, 4: {id:4, name:"hercules vampires parallax", description:"the best game ever"},};
I guess in order for your function to work i have to know the precise number of dimensions inside the original object right ?

Comment: Its still 2 dimensions. The error is being caused by the id property, which is a number not a string. You can add `toString()` to fix this. See the updated code.

Comment: Ok Got it thanks @Levi. Im trying to understand why do you use the for loop twice and the !hasOwnProperty and hasOwnProperty methods, i have make this function myself and it works but yours seems way much better, will be nice if you can explain those loops just a little bit more, really appreciated.

function buscar (arr, str) {
str = str.toLowerCase();
results = [];
for (var x in arr) {
if (arr[x].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1) {
results.push(arr[x].id);
results.push(arr[x].name);
results.push(arr[x].description); 
};
return (results);
};

console.log(buscar(game_list, "fruitis");)

Comment: First loop is to iterate through each of the objects in the game_list object. The 2nd loop is to iterate through each of the properties on the individual object, and search for the string within it. `hasOwnProperty` ensures that the property being accessed is truly part of the object, and not something inherited.

Comment: See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty